# Find the largest common part of two strings using Vim script

Tags: regex, vim, regex-greedy

I have two string variables. The second string is a changed version of the first. Like this:

```
let a = 'this is a string'
let b = 'oh this is another string'
```

I would like to find the largest substring that is in both.

In the example the result would be `this is a`.

What is the easiest way to do this in Vim, considering the variables may contain an arbitrary line of text?

My initial idea was to concat both strings

`this is a string|oh this is another string`

and then use `matchlist()` with this regex:

`\v(.+).*\|.*\1`

Unfortunately, the group in the parentheses just matched `' string'`.

Comment: You could try translating one of [these](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_implementation/Strings/Longest_common_substring) implementations into vimscript.

Comment: Funny, I tried `:echo matchlist('this is a string|oh this is another string', '\v(.+).*\|.*\1')` and the second item of the List was `'this is a'`, not `' string'`.  But that is because `'this is a'` comes first, not because it is longest.  I am not sure that this is possible with regular expressions.  @Jeff's suggestion might be the best way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function! LongestCommonSubstring(foo, bar)
  let longest = ''
  for n in range(strlen(a:foo))
    let common = matchlist(strpart(a:foo, n) . '|' . a:bar, '\v(.+).*\|.*\1')[1]
    if strlen(common) > strlen(longest)
      let longest = common
    endif
  endfor
  return longest
endfun
```

For long strings, it is probably less efficient than the algorithms in @Jeff's link, but it handles `this is a string` and `oh this is another string` fine.

The longest line is exactly 80 characters, so by the usual standards it is OK, but it is dense enough that it might be clearer to split it up:

```
    let pasted = strpart(a:foo, n) . '|' . a:bar
    let common = matchlist(pasted, '\v(.+).*\|.*\1')[1]
```

or perhaps

```
    let common = matchstr(pasted, '\v\zs(.+)\ze.*\|.*\1')
```

Of course, this only works if `|` is not in either string.